# RxDart CombineLatest emit no data

Tags: dart, rxdart

I'm doing small project with `FLUTTER/DART` and `RXDART`.

Here is part of the code:

```html
class RegisterBloc with UserValidator {
final _username = BehaviorSubject<String>();
final _email = BehaviorSubject<String>();
final _password = BehaviorSubject<String>();

Function(String) get setUsername => _username.sink.add;
Stream<String> get username => _username.stream.transform(usernameValidatorTransformer);

Function(String) get setEmail => _email.sink.add;
Stream<String> get email => _email.stream.transform(emailValidatorTransformer);

Function(String) get setPassword => _password.sink.add;
Stream<String> get password => _password.stream.transform(passwordValidatorTransformer);

Stream<bool> get validForm => CombineLatestStream.combine3<String, String, String, bool>(_username.stream, _email.stream, _password.stream, (u, e, p) => true);

submit() async {
 final form = RegisterForm(
  username: _username.value,
  email: _email.value,
  password: _password.value
 );
}

dispose() {
 _username.close();
 _email.close();
 _password.close();
}
}
```

The Problem is validForm Stream emit null data and combiner never get called, even all streams already emit at least 1 value.
What worst, this only happen on Android (mine v.8.1.0), the codes work just as expected on iOS 11.

In case anyone wondering, i use StreamBuilder widget to update widget data.

Do i missing something here? any configuration need to be set prior or else.

[image]

Here my Development Environment:

```html
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G6030, locale en-ID)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

RxDart: 0.21.0
Android Device: 8.1.0

Comment: Unrelated, but be careful about getters for streams. The `Stream<String> get email => _email.stream.transform(emailValidatorTransformer);` will cause `email == email` to be false - always, because you pipe it through a transformer. It can cause problem with Flutters change detection. I've seen the above code spread like wildfire, and it's not the best idea.

Comment: @DarkNeuron I have a problem with "Observable.combineLatest" it gives me wrong values and I am wondering if that transformer causes that, could you elaborate why "pipe it through a transformer" is a bad idea in that case

Comment: Sounds unrelated. I'm talking about the OP's `transform()`. In broad terms: `The output of a function will usually result in a new object`, so in the OP's case, if you did the comparison `transform(someValue) == transform(someValue)` will always result in `false`. Flutter's change detector checks for equality between objects before deciding to draw a new frame. So using getters that always return new objects, can be bad, since it breaks equality. I tend to avoid it.

Comment: @DarkNeuron, If that is the case when comparing, what do you think about comparing the value of the output of the `transform` instead of comparing the objects?

Comment: Does your `transform` output an object? If so, it could be trouble. The problematic use case I'm talking about if you have a StreamBuilder that uses a getter, like this: `StreamBuilder(stream: myObject.myGetter)`. If `myGetter` returns your stream (via `transform`), it will be a new stream every time, and Flutter will tend to rebuild when the equality checks fail. So the solution is to have an initState (or something to that effect), and store the output of `myGetter` in an object. This will cause the stream object to be unchanging, and the equality check wont cause problems. Hope thats clear.

Answer (score 0):

I did a project like this and it's working correctly, everything in ur bloc class is ok, i guess the problem is in ur validator class, if u shared ur validation class maybe i could help u more,
Here my codes
Its the bloc class :

```
class Bloc with Validator {
  final _emailController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _passwordController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _textController = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  // add to stream
  Function(String) get reciveText => _textController.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changeEmail => _emailController.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changePassword => _passwordController.sink.add;

  // access to stream
  Stream<String> get emailvalidation =>
      _emailController.stream.transform(validateEmail);
  Stream<String> get passwordvalidation =>
      _passwordController.stream.transform(validatePassword);
  Stream<bool> get submitValid =>
      Rx.combineLatest2(emailvalidation, passwordvalidation, (a, b) => true);
  Stream<String> get accesstext =>
      _textController.stream.transform(validateText);

  submit() {
    final validemail = _emailController.value;
    final validpass = _passwordController.value;
    reciveText('user name : $validemail \n pass : $validpass ');
    print('all valid');
  }
```

And its validation codes :

```
final validateEmail = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (data, sink) {
      if (data.contains('@') && data.contains('.')) {
        sink.add(data);
      } else {
        sink.addError('Enter Valid emaill');
      }
    },
  );
  final validatePassword = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (data, sink) {
      if (data.length > 3) {
        sink.add(data);
      } else {
        sink.addError('Password is too short');
      }
    },
  );
```

by the way u can see my codes that are working fine in my GitHub, maybe it help u to see what is going wrong in ur project.

https://github.com/Manticodes/flutter_loginscreen_blocpattern

I hope it help u to solve ur problem.